# Activate App but keep script running Applescript

Tags: applet, applescript

I would like to open another app (applescript applet) with Applescript but still move on to the next line in my script.

I though it would automatically do this but it does not for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
...
if selectedMenu is "1" then
        set theDisplay to "⬟"
        my display(theDisplay)
        tell application "/Users/Patrick/Documents/Programming/Applescript/Applications/NoWatch.app/Contents/Resources/Both.app" to activate
        tell application "/Users/Patrick/Documents/Programming/Applescript/Applications/NoWatch.app/Contents/Resources/VNC.app" to quit saving no
        tell application "/Users/Patrick/Documents/Programming/Applescript/Applications/NoWatch.app/Contents/Resources/SSH.app" to quit saving no
...
```

I included the part after the activation just incase that is what is causing this.

Also, after closing the app I activated, the script continues like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ignoring application responses
    tell application "Finder" to activate
 end ignoring
```